# How can I customize the horizontal axis values in excel?

Tags: excel, graph, axis

So I am trying to make a nice line graph for some data that I have. Each line has 100 data points, so excel automatically makes the horizontal axis from 1-100. I want to change the min/max values for the horizontal axis from 0-1, without moving the frame of the graph (i.e. without zooming in the graph). I just want to divide the horizontal axis numbers by 100 in order to rescale the time. This is what my graph looks like now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fWUd.jpg

So I want to change the numbers on the horizontal axis to be fractions or decimals in the range [0,1]. Does anyone know how I can do this, or any other graphing software that would allow me to do this (I have tried using google sheets, but they have less options to customize axes than excel). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use two column to plot one line and did you use the Scatter with smooth lines chart type?

Have one column (X) go from 0 to 1 using intervals of 0.01 and your data in your second column (Y). When using a scatter with smooth lines chart type your answer should look like this:

[image graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjxaE.jpg)

Plotting your second line in the same chart can be done the same way by adding it through the 'select data' options of the chart.